# KingswaySoft data migration from Dynamics crm 4.0 to 365 id not exist error

Tags: dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

I have already migrated the contact and account tables. There is a table in Extensions and I tried to migrate it, while it contents fields link to other tables like Contact. When I try to migrate, an error happen and it says an id of this table does not exist. This is very confusing. How can it says an id of the table I try to migrate does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you shared with us, it seems that you need to create the dependent records first to maintain the parent-child relationship within the customer entity. Hope this helps.